No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration
I am trying to create a table in MySQL WorkBench using Spring Boot.
Configuration is as below:
spring.application.name=demo

spring.datasource.platform=mysql

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys

spring.datasource.username=root

spring.datasource.password=Reading@1234

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jsp.show-sql=true

Getting 'No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration' error while trying to create a table using spring boot. How to set the JTA platform.
No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration.

That is not an error just an informational message.
